# Createing Expression<Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>>>?

Tags: c#, expression, linq-expressions

I wanna create an `Expression<Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>>>`, I have the following codes :

```
Expression selector = q => q.RegistrationDate

MethodInfo orderByMethodInfo = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().First(method => method.Name == "OrderBy" && method.GetParameters().Count() == 2).MakeGenericMethod(argumentTypes);
MethodInfo orderByDescMethodInfo = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().First(method => method.Name == "OrderByDescending" && method.GetParameters().Count() == 2).MakeGenericMethod(argumentTypes);
```

I'm gonna create `c => c.OrderBy(q => q.RegistrationDate)` or `c => c.OrderByDescending(q => q.RegistrationDate)` or generally something like `c => c.OrderByDescending(q => q.RegistrationDate).ThenBy(q=>q.Name)` from above codes.

Could you please guide how I can do it?

Comment: You could use [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) for this.

Comment: How? Could you please describe more ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IQueryable<T>))
var orderByExpr = Expression.Call(orderByMethodInfo, paramExpr, selector);
var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>>>(orderByExpr, paramExpr);
```

Where `T` is the type with the `RegistrationDate` property in your `selector` expression.

You can get the queryable type from the argument type using `MakeGenericType`:

```
Type argType = typeof(DateTime);
Type queryableType = typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(argType);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But in first line, How can I create `IQueryable<>` from a Type. e.g: I have the type of T(not in generic) as DateTime, how I can create `IQueryable<DateTime>` dynamically ?